# I want to Serialize dept_name as well as it's "id" in one single model serializer. How should I do it?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I want to serialize "Department name"(dept_name) as well as Department ID(id) in the Employee Model Serializer from department Model

In the Employee Serializer I want to Serialize "Department name" as well as "Dept ID" models. I mentioned Department Model in class Meta of Employee Serializer as well

## MODELS

```
class Department(models.Model):
    dept_name = models.CharField(max_length=10)


class Employee(models.Model):
    emp_name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=14)
    designation = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    dept_id = models.ForeignKey(Department, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('id',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.emp_name
```

## SERIALIZER

```
class DepartmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Department
        fields = [
            'id',
            'dept_name',
        ]


class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    dept_id = serializers.SlugRelatedField(queryset=Department.objects.all(), slug_field='dept_name')
    deptname = DepartmentSerializer()
    
    class Meta:
        model = Employee,Department
        fields = [
            'id',
            'emp_name',
            'email',
            'password',
            'designation',
            'dept_id',
            'deptname',
        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember to select_related('dept') on your Employee queryset.

```
class Department(models.Model):
    dept_name = models.CharField(max_length=10)


class Employee(models.Model):
    emp_name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=14)
    designation = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    # .._id suffix django will implement automatically
    dept = models.ForeignKey(Department, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True) 

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('id',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.emp_name


class DepartmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Department
        fields = ('id', 'dept_name')


class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    dept = DepartmentSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = ('id',
                  'emp_name',
                  'email',
                  'password',
                  'designation',
                  'dept')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use depth in in `EmployeeSerializer`. It will return all department object's fields.

=================
depth = 1 => returns one level of depth.
depth = 2 => returns two levels of depth.

like this :

```
class DepartmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Department
        fields = '__all__'


class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = '__all__'
        depth = 1
```